# I need to scroll down until the search result complete in e-commerce website using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I want to scroll down bottom of the page

Expected Steps:

1. open the Application website (www.jabong.com)
2. I search the Men Watches in search box
3. Page will give the search results. Here i need to scroll down the page until the page has complete the search result.

I hope understand my questions. I tried the below code for scrolldown using selenium

```
WebElement bottomButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='catalog-product']/footer/button"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        do{
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(bottomButton));
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
            bottomButton.click();
        }while(!bottomButton.isDisplayed());
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
js.executeScript("scroll(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

I remember I tried window.scrollBy, and it didn't work too, don't know why...

Comment: This code for scroll down but i need continuous execution till page load complete.